# Getting HTTP response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url

In my Rails controller, I have the `url` that the user inputs:

```
url_parsed = URI.parse(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_parsed)
```

If the user inputs `www.google.com`, it gives

```
undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x00000002e07908 URL:www.google.com>
```

on the line `response = ...`.

I want it to display my error page, instead of this error. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if your question is why it isn't working, or how to use the error message in the view.

**Why you get the error**

**EDIT:**

I think that it's because there is no protocol in `'www.google.com'`, `'http://www.google.com'` should work

**How to show the error**

Rescue the error:

```
error = nil
begin
  url_parsed = URI.parse(url)
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_parsed)
rescue => error
end
if error
  @error_message = "Your URL wasn't good enough"
  # or you can use error.message if you want
  # then use @error_message in your view
else
  # do stuff when ok
end
```